# gitlab api equivalent to git log (compare branch with tag) and list commit message json

Tags: rest, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

i need some equivalent command to the following command:

```
git log --pretty="* %s%n%b" BRANCH2...TAGNAME1
```

i tried already the compare feature of the api but sadly without the result i expected:

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXX" "https://gitlab.localhost/api/v4/projects/3/repository/compare?from=BRANCH2&to=TAGNAME1&straight=true" | jq .
```

what i get is:

```
  "commit": null,
  "commits": [],
```

but git log gives me the following:

```
 * commit 1 description
 * commit 2 description
```

so what i search and need is to compare BRANCH2 with TAGNAME1 and list the different commits.
this is later on needed in order to generate a changelog file which is pushed to a new tag.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the [compare API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits)

Using the `gitlab-org/gitlab` repo as an example, to compare the tags/branches `v14.8.0-ee` to `v14.9.0-ee`:

```sh
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964/repository/compare?from=v14.8.0-ee&to=v14.9.0-ee
```

If you're not getting the response you're expecting, try swapping the `from` and `to` arguments and/or omitting the `straight` argument.

Answer (score 0):

thank you!
the solution in the end was change the from and to so in the end it works like that:

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXX" "https://gitlab.localhost/api/v4/projects/3/repository/compare?from=TAGNAME1&to=BRANCH2&straight=true" | jq .
```

Answer (score 0):

Following command can be used to get the exact response similar to your expectation with *git log*

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "http://<gitlab-endpoint>/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/repository/compare?from=<tag>&to=<tag>&straight=true" | jq '.commits[]|.title'
```